# append script to class / DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I am trying to append the following script in tampermonkey which should insert a script (adtag banner) into a div / class of a specific website but its not working.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Insert TAG Into Class- zeit.com
// @require  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// @match       http*://www.website.xxx/*
// ==/UserScript==


(function () {
    var scriptElement = document.createElement( "script" );
    scriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
    scriptElement.src = "HTML SOURCE";
    $(".header").append(scriptElement);
})();
```

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `"HTML SOURCE"` - you're replacing this with.. ? an html file?  It should be the url to the .js file (so would appear above as "JS SOURCE" not "HTML SOURCE".

Comment: What does `console.log($(".header").length)` give you when placed just before your `var script...` line

Comment: @freedomn-m: the console logs a 1

Comment: @freedomn-m: its a JS like this: http://track.adform.net/adfscript/?bn=XXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try this

```
$(".header").append(`<script type="text/javascript" src="../path"></script>`)
```

Comment: hey @Sven.hig i tried this 
```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Insert IMAGE Into Class
// @require  https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
// @match       http*://www.website.com/*
// ==/UserScript==


$("#iq-standard-banner-927305506").append(`<script type="text/javascript" src=" track.adform.net/adfscript/?bn=XXXXXXXXXX"></script>`)
```

But its not working